# Sort SQL ORDER BY query without slashes in front of escaped characters

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by, stripslashes, addslashes

I am trying to figure out how to sort an SQL query by Last Name.  This is working except in the case of where a customers last name has a special character.

For example O'Maley.

If this last name is sorted with a last name of "Omar" for example the order should be:

O'Maley
Omar

BUT since I use addslashes() in PHP before adding it into the database the sort is actually happening on O\'Maley and so the sort ends up being.

Omar
O'Maley

Of course the \ is removed with stripslashes() before being displayed to the user.

How can I make this properly sort?

Comment: You should get the slashes out of your data.  You double escaped before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using either the `REPLACE()` or `TRANSLATE()` sql functions.  For example:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(last_name, '\\', ''), ''', '')
```

The above `REPLACE()` functions will remove the backslashes and single quotes before doing the order by.

```
ORDER BY TRANSLATE(last_name, '\\'', '')
```

The above `TRANSLATE()` function will also remove the backslashes and single quotes.  This might be a better format for specifying many more characters to remove from a string.

Note: You don't mention a database, so I'm assuming Oracle.  Most databases have equivalent functions.